# Sort database table by highest number of occurences of an id mysql/php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table 'favoriteSellers' with columns

```
uniqueId userId sellerId
1        33     31
2        33     32
3        31     32
4        32     33
5        32     32
6        31     33
```

I need to be able to call the most favorited sellerIds in order. So in the above it would return Id 32, then 33, then 31

I have no idea the correct sql statement to do this!

Comment: a GROUP BY statement with a COUNT statement as part of your SELECT would be a good starting point.... but you're more likely to get answers to a question here on StackOverflow if you can show that you've made at least some effort yourself before asking for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT sellerId, COUNT(*) AS bestSeller 
FROM favoriteSellers 
ORDER BY bestSeller DESC`

Try this. just off the top off my head I think this may do what you wish